# Cross product in c++

Tags: c++, python

Given the following Python (from http://norvig.com/sudoku.html)

```
def cross(A, B):
    "Cross product of elements in A and elements in B."
    return [a+b for a in A for b in B]

cols     = '123456789'
rows     = 'ABCDEFGHI'
squares  = cross(rows, cols)
```

This produces:

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', ...]
```

As an exercise, I want to do the same in C++.  Currently I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

static vector<string> cross_string(const string &A, const string &B)
{
    vector<string> result;

    for (string::const_iterator itA = A.begin(); itA != A.end(); ++itA) {
        for (string::const_iterator itB = B.begin(); itB != B.end(); ++itB) {
            char s[] = {*itA, *itB, 0};
            result.push_back(string(s));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char digits[] = "123456789";
    const char rows[]   = "ABCDEFGHI";

    vector<string> res = cross_string(rows, digits);

    for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = res.begin();
         it != res.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This works, but I was hoping there would be a better way.  This also does only strings, whereas the python does any list...

---

Edit:

Thanks for all of the replies. I accepted the one that I understood best, but Alf's answer was a close second.  I note that all used C++11 and wonder whether as a novice at C++ I should adopt that directly instead of the learning the older standard.  But that is perhaps best for another question.

Comment: Belongs on [codereview.se] if anywhere.

Comment: @millimoose: How so? Asking how to best calculate this (which is slightly different from asking how to improve the given code) seems like a valid question for SO. If it didn't include the code it would definately belong here and I don't think that showing, that the author already tried it, changes things.

Comment: @Grizzly SO is for "I'm trying to do X and failing because Y." Code Review is "I've done X and it works but I don't like it." The criterium I'm applying is the lack of a well-defined problem that would need solving. ("I think there might be a better solution" doesn't really provide a clear bar for an answer to clear.)

Comment: @millimoose: I think he's stated a well-defined problem that needs solving: "it only works for strings". Making it work for other types seems to me like a pretty clear bar for the answer to clear.

Comment: @millimoose: The way I see it Code Review is for "here is my code, any suggestions how to improve it", while SO is "I have this problem, how to solve it". The question could've made it more clear, but the implied how to make this work for other types and how to write this more elegantely (which seems like a natural interpretation for better when the much shorter python code is given) seem concrete enough for me that it belongs here rather then Code Review (so basically I disagree on the point of the question missing a well-defined problem).

Comment: @Grizzly "How to make this work for any type?" is a valid SO question, but it's something that should be asked outright, instead of implying it or mentioning it off hand in the coda. What the OP really wanted is up to them to decide and phrase. Also, "How to write this more elegantly?" is just another way of saying "I don't like it."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weirdly enough, `cross_product` is missing from the C++ algorithms library. It can easily be added but as Jerry’s and Alf’s answers show, opinions differ on how to do it best. In fact, I’d do it different still. Jerry’s interface conforms to that of the other C++ algorithms but he didn’t abstract away the cross product operation, which I’d do thusly:

```
template <typename InputIt1,
          typename InputIt2,
          typename OutputIt,
          typename F>
void cross_product(InputIt1 begin1,
                   InputIt1 end1,
                   InputIt2 begin2,
                   InputIt2 end2,
                   OutputIt out,
                   F f) {
    for (auto i = begin1; i != end1; ++i)
        for (auto j = begin2; j != end2; ++j)
            *out++ = f(*i, *j);
}
```

The call, in your example, would then look as follows:

```
auto digits = "1234546789";
auto chars = "ABCDEFGHI";
vector<string> result;

cross_product(digits, digits + strlen(digits),
              chars, chars + strlen(chars),
              back_inserter(result),
              [](char a, char b) { return string() + a + b; });
```

(Don’t I just love C++11? Yes, I do.)

In a proper library I’d offer a second overload which supplies a default `f` operation which creates a tuple similar to what Jerry’s code does. It would even be thinkable to abstract this further to allow more than two ranges – after all, the Python list comprehension allows you to iterate over more than two ranges).

Comment: re "opinions differ on how to do it best", i think these approaches are not really competing. i chose to write what the OP directly required, a *function*. with more time it would be refactored to internally use something like Jerry's code, which would also be offered. that in turn would be refactored to use your more general code, which would also be offered... so it's not like either/or. it's like, everything, thanks!

Comment: on a related note, i think part of what makes C++ so inaccessible to newbies is the lack of reasonable defaults and proper "everything" instead of "either/or" in the standard library. e.g., a `sort` where one could just write `sort( a )`. instead of `sort( begin( a ), end( a ) )`, which is way too verbose and with way too many degrees of freedom for the most common case, IMHO.

Comment: They tried to add container based algorithms in C++11 and failed due to technical headaches.  Probably because concepts fell out, and concepts would make container based algorithms easy...

Answer (score 5):

Well it's shorter to just present the code than to explain:

```
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout, std::endl
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <utility>          // std::begin, std::end
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string sum( char const a, char const b ) { return string() + a + b; }

template< class Container >
auto cross( Container const& a, Container const& b )
    -> vector< decltype( sum( *begin( a ), *begin( b ) ) ) >
{
    typedef decltype( sum( *begin( a ), *begin( b ) ) ) ResultItem;
    vector< ResultItem >   result;

    for( auto&& itemA : a ) for( auto&& itemB : b )
    {
        result.push_back( sum( itemA, itemB ) );
    }
    return result;
}

wostream& operator<<( wostream& stream, string const& s )
{
    return (stream << s.c_str());
}

template< class Item >
wostream& operator<<( wostream& stream, vector<Item> const& v )
{
    stream << "[";
    bool isFirstItem = true;
    for( auto&& item : v )
    { 
        if( !isFirstItem ) { stream << ", "; }
        stream << item;
        isFirstItem = false;
    }
    stream << "]";
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    string const cols       = "123456789";
    string const rows       = "ABCDEFGHI";
    auto const squares      = cross( cols, rows );

    wcout << squares << endl;
}
```

Comment: @William: it's a C++11 feature. you either need a more up-to-date compiler, or to use a compiler option that enables c++11 features.

Comment: Extending this to nary cross product is amusing, esp if you want to reduce the number of constructed strings to logarithmic on the size of the product.  Of course that is silly, because output size grows exponentially in number of inputs, but...

Comment: @William: clang is pretty close to gcc, and as it turns out the code compiles fine with MinGW g++ 4.7.1. sorry, i don't have clang installed (exception handling reportedly doesn't work in windows, still).

Comment: @WilliamMorris: as a matter of principle, I'm against "cleaning up comments", because that's **altering history**. Think about cleaning up the Nurnberg protocols, removing all that doesn't seem relevant at the moment, or removing one point of view only. Of course, now I've mentioned a connection to **Hitler** there can be no more serious comments here, and it sort of puts the now deleted comments from you in a different light! See?

Comment: I thought it more a matter of whether the comments are helpful to subsequent readers.  My problems with compilers probably wont :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could certainly make this generic:

```
template <class InIt1, class InIt2, class OutIt>
void cross_product(InIt1 b1, InIt1 e1, InIt2 b2, InIt2 e2, OutIt out) {  
    for (auto i=b1; i != e1; ++i) 
        for (auto j=b2; j != e2; ++j) 
            *out++ = std::make_pair(*i, *j);
}
```

Note that you don't generally want the template parameters to be the types of the objects in the collections, but the types of iterators to the collections. For example, you could use this like this:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::pair<char, int> const &d) { 
    return os << d.first << d.second;
}

int main() { 
    std::vector<char> a{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
    std::vector<int> b{ 1, 2, 3, 4};

    cross_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),
        infix_ostream_iterator<std::pair<char, int> >(std::cout, ", "));
    return 0;
}
```

...which should produce output like this:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, C1, C2, C3, C4, D1, D2, D3, D4
```

Also note that I've used some C++11 features throughout most of this code. If you're using an older compiler (or one from Microsoft) it'll need a bit of editing.

Comment: uhm, short and tidy ... now make that a *function*? <g>

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Is there something in the original post saying he really wants it to be a function? If so, I must have missed it. He gives a function, and says he's hoping for "a better way", but I don't see anything even implying that the "better way" would necessarily be a function.

Comment: Hm, well, things that imply the OP wants a function... How about, "I want to do the same in C++", after the Python example. Or, how about the C++ example that is a function? But really, no matter whether the OP desires it or not, it is about centralizing the nitty-gritty of providing a result variable etc., so that the calling code is cleaner and more expression oriented. That's what much of the point of move semantics is/was about, by the way, so you can see it's important. Andrei tried with his "Mojo" in C++03. But C++11 solution is much cleaner. Expressions, not commands! :-)

Comment: Thanks Jerry.  Is there a non-11 way of doing the vector initialisation (`a{'A', 'B'...`})? And is `infix_ostream_iterator` yours or a common thing?

Comment: @WilliamMorris: Without C++11, about the best you can do for vector initialization is probably [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html). I posted `infix_ostream_iterator` in a [previous question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489).

Answer (score 0):

templatize for classes A and B. then make pairs `std::pair<A, B>`