# Make a combination of two arrays to form a pair of each item

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two arrays array1 of size 3 and array2 of size 2. I wish to form a pair of each item from both arrays. That is;

```
int array1[] = {1, 2, 3};
int array2[] = {9, 4};
```

Results I'm hoping to achieve:
1 , 9 
1 , 4 
2 , 9 
2 , 4 
3 , 9 
3 , 4

This is what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int array1[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int array2[] = {9, 4};

    int arrayOneSize = sizeof(array1);
    int arrayTwoSize = sizeof(array2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrayOneSize; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < arrayTwoSize; j++)
        {
            cout << array1[i] << " , " << array2[j] << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason I am getting a whole bunch of weird combinations like: 
1,9
1,4
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,1029505037
1,-531587312
...             (It's really long, just want to shorten the results a little)
0,-411331072
1,9
1,4
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,1029505037
1,-531587312
1,-411331072

Sorry for the noob question. I am still new to C++ so, I will gladly appreciate any help. And also why am I getting numbers which are not part of the array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int arrayOneSize = sizeof(array1);` ==> `int arrayOneSize = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(*array1);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: `sizeof` is not the number of elements.

Comment: maybe not that obvious, but this question is very similar and the accepted answer shows a generic solution that you could also apply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788114/cross-product-in-c

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the number of elements in an array, you have to divide its size by the size of an element in it:

```
int arrayOneSize = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]);
int arrayTwoSize = sizeof(array2) / sizeof(array2[0]);
```

As [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) points out, you can use the [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for the arrays and bypass finding the size manually all-together.
Alternatively, consider using `std::array`, or better yet, `std::vector`. Here's an implementation with modern C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector vec1{ 1, 2, 3 };  // no need for <int> with C++17
  std::vector vec2{ 9, 4 };

  for (auto&& e1 : vec1) {
    for (auto&& e2 : vec2) {
      std::cout << e1 << " , " << e2
                << '\n';  // no need to flush the buffer all the time
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, for-range is also available for `int array1[] = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: do you know of any STL algorithm that accomplishes that ? feels like a lot of boiler plate

Comment: @WalidJabari `std::size` does that.

Comment: I was refering to the part that generates all the possible permutations

Comment: @WalidJabari [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: uh, had that one in mind too, I guess there's no better way than 2 for-loops. thx anyway

Comment: @wal on the second look, next_permutation is not really suitable here. You can always write your own function though.

Answer (score 2):

The size ( no. of elements in each array) computation of arrays is having the issue.

```
int arrayOneSize = sizeof(array1);
int arrayTwoSize = sizeof(array2);
```

This will be number of elements * sizeof(int) which gives the total size. Since you are interested only in number of elements, you should rather do

```
int arrayOneSize = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int);
int arrayTwoSize = sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int);
```

This should give the expected output